# Is the question/day limit per site or across the network?

Tags: support, voting, voting-limits

In [Optimizing for Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), Jeff says that:

> We now limit users (and IP addresses) to a maximum of 6 questions per day and 50 questions per month.

Is this a per-site limit or a per-network limit?  It seems quite possible that a single IP address could generate more good questions that this across the wide range of Stack Exchange sites that exist.

For example, when working (at home) I have two good questions about [programming](http://stackexchange.com) and [database management](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), then when I'm not working I have questions about [the meal I'm planning to make](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [how to best photograph that meal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) for the blog post I'm going to write, and then late at night I need [clarification about the rules of a game I'm playing.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)  During the day, I also have a good idea about [how to improve traffic at the beta site I'm involved with](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com), and [trigger a bug that I would like to report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

This may seem like a bit of stretch now, but assuming the number of Area51 graduates continues to increase, it will become less and less of one.

Comment: Your middle paragraph reads (in a good way!) like ad copy for the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limit mentioned in the blog post is a per-site one.