# Is there no question limit during beta?

Tags: support, questions, private-beta

[Cognitive Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149/cognitive-sciences) is currently in private beta for 4 days. We had [one user](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/42/inquilinekea) who [posted an immense amount of questions](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/21) in the first few days.

Judging [from this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95013/is-the-question-day-limit-per-site-or-across-the-network), I would believe this isn't possible, as the limit is 6 questions per day. Are there different rules for private beta/public beta?

Comment: Great question! I was under the impression those rules were widely in effect at all times.

Comment: The user definitely posted 38 questions in one day, maybe 2 days. I can see having a slightly higher limit for private beta (maybe) but nearly 40 questions in a day is way too many. We're still struggling to deal with the questions because we can't easily close them all.

Comment: There could well be, especially in private beta. Part of the idea of private beta is to get as many ideas out there as possible, both to jumpstart the community and so you can discuss and decide which types of questions are on or off topic.

Comment: Are the questions at least good? I can't see them, since it's still a *private* beta.

Comment: @BenBrocka Without being able to see the questions, I'm getting the impression that the user did not bless the site with a proliferation of high-quality content (i.e. the question limit would have been a good thing)?

Comment: The question limit applies only to part of the network.

[Source][1].


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95482/is-the-daily-question-limit-actually-being-enforced

Comment: @jadarnel27 They were clearly seeding the site which is [frowned upon](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/), many of them were okay but overly broad, some were fine, some were just plain bad. I think if the user had posted a few initially we could have helped flesh out which were appropriate and which weren't before ALL the bad ones were posted.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Hm, perhaps a more lenient limit would be more applicable to smaller sites.6 questions is possible, 40 questions seems unreasonable.

Comment: @Ben I didn't make those rules, but I think Jeff is correct - "on smaller sites, this should be handled by the site moderators on a case by case basis" - some people can greatly contribute to smaller sites to grow.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd a problem with private beta sites is we effectively *have* no moderators. Only SE employees have moderator status on our sites and they don't rigorously use the sites enough to see issues like this.

Comment: @Ben so just report such things here and I'm sure the devs will look into it - IMO the potential to get good start is greater than the risk of having a troll.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question limit applies only to part of the network.

I will quote Jeff:

> That limit is only enabled on the SOFU trilogy for now, that is, sites that regularly get 100+ questions per day. (Stack Overflow alone gets 3.5k+ per day..)
>
> Our thinking was that on smaller sites, this should be handled by the site moderators on a case by case basis, rather than through an algorithm.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95671/152859).

Obviously, unborn site is considered "smaller site". :)

Comment: Exactly what is intended with: _"this should be handled"_ when there aren't any moderators? Either way, this answers the question. I might ask for a feature request later as I feel this really hurt the private beta instead of helping it.

Comment: @StevenJeuris The community team monitors private beta sites and acts as moderators. If there's an issue with a user, flag one of their posts or make a meta post and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Steven - the about page of the site should contain list of the moderators. They are those who will handle such things. If you do as Anna suggested and still not satisfied there's also email address in the about page that you can use.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: A private beta doesn't have any moderators yet. The about page says the moderators are _"TBD"_. Once we go into public beta we'll hopefully get some [Moderator's Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), but the point is the damage has already been done, and judging from the up votes on the comment of [the post you link to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95671/157047) we are not the only ones who experienced this problem.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks, when we can't get the excess bad questions closed we will flag them as such. Meanwhile, we created a [chat room to discuss the cleanup of excess questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2273/cognitive-sciences-meta), where problematic questions are starred.

Comment: @Steven I see.. sorry I can't be of any help and hope you'll have the mess cleaned up before the gates open!