# Apply the question limit on all sites

Tags: feature-request, questions

At the moment the question limit of [6 questions per day and 50 questions per month](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) is only enabled [on the SOFU trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120020/157047).

The reasoning behind this being:

> Our thinking was that on smaller sites, this should be handled by the
> site moderators on a case by case basis, rather than through an
> algorithm.

I see a few flaws in this reasoning:

**Early betas don't have any moderators.** When a user seeds an excess amount of questions there is no easy way to clean them up. While a site is in private beta a consensus hasn't even been built on when to close questions. ([This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120019/157047) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95482/157047) happened before.) As Jeff put it: *"The fastest way to kill any Q&A site is to flood it with low-quality questions."* Wouldn't this apply all the more for betas?

A possible solution to this as phrased [by Anna Lear in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120020/157047):

> The community team monitors private beta sites and acts as moderators.
> If there's an issue with a user, flag one of their posts or make a
> meta post and we'll take a look.

Which gives rise to the following questions:

**How does the community team know what is off-topic/not a real question?** Sites can have a very specific subject making it hard for non-professionals to judge whether a question should be closed. Chances are the scope of the site isn't even properly defined yet.

**Should these excess questions be closed?** Users seeding a site don't necessarily have bad intentions. They can be overly enthusiastic without knowing the ropes of how the system works yet. After feedback the questions can turn out to be proper questions. Do you want to close questions which could belong on the site, just because there isn't enough time to handle them?

And finally possibly the strongest argument:

**What good can come out of more than 6 questions a day?** As [in jjnguy's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89220/157047):

> If you are asking over 2 questions per day, there is a good chance you
> aren't putting enough time into your questions.

Is it even possible to formulate 6 proper questions a day, follow up on them, and process the answers?

---

In my opinion an easier solution is the following:

**Limit the amount of questions a user can ask per day on *all* sites.** The monthly limit of 50 questions per month is probably less important, allowing a bit more free room for smaller sites (were this to be the reasoning). This alleviates all the above mentioned problems, giving moderators-to-be more time to address the issue before the site is flooded with unanswered questions.

Comment: `Is it even possible to formulate 6 proper questions a day, following up on them, and processing the answers?` Yes, especially when seeding on a private beta. However, I would still institute a six per day limit. It's entirely unreasonable to post more than that per day, and if you stretched it out over the entire 24*7 period of the privbeta, that's still 42 Q, which is entirely reasonable. This rate restriction is a good one, and I endorse it on all sites.

Comment: @jcolebrand technically we're not *supposed* to be "seeding" private betas...I agree with your statement in general though.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a question limit. o.o

Comment: @animuson Check out [this amusing post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) then =)

Comment: I think you should ask "How does the community team know what is off-topic/not a real question?" separately, I don't see how it fits here.  It's a good point though -- I wasn't a fan of how Travel was handled in beta.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Part of the point is the need to resort to the community team would arise less quickly if there were to be a question limit.

Comment: Yes, I just don't think how they determine a question is bad is germane to the discussion about a question limit.

Comment: A private beta site is the one place I might allow more than six questions a day. On the theory that the OP has might have a group of "stored up" questions s/he wanted to get off. But I agree, it's hard to formulate six good new questions a day.