# How was this user able to ask four spam questions so quickly?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, spam-detection

[User[9815934087]](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/561/9815934087) was able to ask four spam questions within 45 minutes. How could someone ask that many questions so quickly?

Comment: I remember seeing some spam with "babi ji" and an Indian phone number on SO, not too long back...

Comment: Its supposed to be 20 minutes according to the [rate limiting guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). However the rules might be different on beta sites

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120020/158667 maybe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mat's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181274/how-was-this-user-able-to-ask-four-spam-questions-so-quickly#comment550839_181274) is correct. The rate limit on new users asking questions isn't enabled on most sites at all.

Comment: Anna isn't this a dupe of that other question then? Maybe not 100% same meaning but the duplicate banner says "This question already has an answer here" so...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm not a fan of dupe closures like that. The same answer doesn't mean the questions are the same.